# Register Multiple Interface Implementation In LightInject IoC

Tags: ioc-container, light-inject

I have an `interface` with  two implementations.

```
public interface ILogger
{
   void Log(string message);
}

public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
   public void Log(string message) {}
}

public class SQLiteLogger : ILogger
{
  public void Log(string message) {}
}
```

I try using this code, but doesn't work.

```
ServiceContainer service = new ServiceContainer();
service.Register<ILogger, FileLogger>();
service.Register<ILogger, SQLiteLogger>();
```

`LightInject` will omit the first registration and only register `SQLiteLogger`.
So how to register same interface with multiple implementation in `LightInject` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Named Services](http://www.lightinject.net/#named-services) - which is quite standard across most IOC/DI containers that I've seen (see section on named services).

The documentation provides all the detail you need but here is a cut-and-paste from their website:

```
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>();
container.Register<IFoo, AnotherFoo>("AnotherFoo");
var instance = container.GetInstance<IFoo>("AnotherFoo");
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(instance, typeof(AnotherFoo));
```