# How to Register Multiple Interface Implementation In IoC in MvvmLight?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

> [Register Multiple Interface Implementation In LightInject IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654791/register-multiple-interface-implementation-in-lightinject-ioc)

How to use MvvmLight's Ioc to solve the problem?
I have multiple DataService (DataService1, DataService2, DataService3 ...). They are all IDataService and need to be contacted with multiple ViewModel.
Mvvmlight can't do it：

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService1>("DataService1Key");
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService2>("DataService2Key");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use 'class' key identifiers in MvvmLight, like so

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataClass>(() => c1, "Class1");
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataClass>(() => c2, "Class2");

var t = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDataClass>("Class1");
var s = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDataClass>("Class2");
```