# LightInject - Register multiple implementation of same interface

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, light-inject

Using Lightinjector DI framework how to register multiple implementation of same interface? how to mention the same interface on constructor and ask for its different implementation?

```
     container.Register<IInterface1, Myclass1>();
     container.Register<IInterface1, Myclass2>();
```

While trying Annotation, encountered below exception

```
 "message": "Unable to resolve type: 
    "innererror": {
      "trace": "   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDelegate(Type serviceType, String serviceName, Boolean throwError) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\build\\tmp\\netstandard16\\Binary\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 3901\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.CreateDefaultDelegate(Type serviceType, Boolean throwError) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\build\\tmp\\netstandard16\\Binary\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 3859\r\n   at LightInject.ServiceContainer.TryGetInstance(Type serviceType) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\build\\tmp\\netstandard16\\Binary\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 2777\r\n   at LightInject.Scope.WithThisScope[T](Func`1 function) in C:\\projects\\lightinject\\build\\tmp\\netstandard16\\Binary\\LightInject\\LightInject.cs:line 6169\r\n
```

Container registration as below,

```
     container.EnableAnnotatedPropertyInjection();
     container.Register<ILoginHandler, LoginHandler>("LoginHandler");
```

Constructor injection on class "User.cs" as below,

```
public class User
{
   public ILoginHandler _loginHandler { get; private  set; }    
   public class([Inject(serviceName: "LoginHandler")]ILoginHandler loginHandler)
   {
      _loginHandler = loginHandler;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Register Multiple Interface Implementation In LightInject IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654791/register-multiple-interface-implementation-in-lightinject-ioc)

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Named Services](http://www.lightinject.net/#named-services) - which is quite standard across most IOC/DI containers that I've seen (see section on named services).

```
 container.Register<IInterface1, Myclass1>("Foo");
 container.Register<IInterface1, Myclass2>("Bar");
 var instance = container.GetInstance<IInterface1>("Foo");
 Assert.IsInstanceOfType(instance, typeof(Myclass1));
```

Makes sense? :)

```
 public class FooWithNamedAnnotatedProperyDependency
{
    [Inject("Foo")]
    public IInterface1 Service { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public FooWithNamedAnnotatedDependency([Inject(ServiceName="Foo")]IInterface1 service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

[look at annotations](https://www.lightinject.net/annotation/)

Comment: Above code is about registering various implementation of same interface with LightInjector. But how to do dependency injection via constructor, how or what to declare in the constructor to inject Myclass1 not Myclass2 instance?

Comment: Look at the last part with Annotations

Comment: Tried Annotation but encountered exception as mentioned above.

Comment: You wrote "LoginHandler", but in your container you write "LoginHelpParagraphHandler", Seems you have typed the wrong name. Thats why it can't find it.

Comment: Thats typo while doing posting here, corrected typo. Issue persists!

Comment: If possible shared codebase and check for more typos.

Comment: Can "LightInject.AutoFactory"  be used for injecting different implementation of same interface?

Comment: Its working now after making parameter less constructor for target class ie., "LoginHandler" in my case. Would like to know how to use Annotations for classes with constructor taking parameters.